# Responsividade do bootstrap em telas grandes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou criando um site em bootstrap4 e ele está quebrando/ficando estranho em telas com mais de 1300px.

Esse é o comportamento padrão do bs nesses casos? 
O que posso fazer para que o layout fique igual ao desejado?

Edit: percebi que não deveria ter postado a imagem do layout do site ou o código e por isso excluir da publicação.

Answer (score 2):

Duas formas que me vem na cabeça agora para "ajustar" isso seriam:

1º Já que está usando **Bootstrap 4** colocar todo o seu código dentro de um `<div class="container-fluid">` não esquecendo de fechar a `</div>` no final.

2º  outra é:

```
<style>    
        @media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
          body{
            width: 1920px;
          }
        }
</style>
```

Isso vai evitar os elementos fujam ao tamanho desejado, você pode definir para tamanhos maiores ainda.

Comment: Tentei as duas soluções e não houve nenhuma mudança no comportamento.

Comment: Fica difícil ajudar sem o código HTML, sem o CSS, no teu caso você precisa tratar a largura máxima da pagina...

Comment: Faz todo sentido cara, mas foi melhor tirar. Mas acho que consegui uma solução, coloquei a imagem de background dentro de um jumbotron e estou tentando controlar o tamanho agora...